Is there a way to get Google Ads remarketing audience size in BigQuery?
We are currently trying to visualize changes in Google Ads remarketing audience sizes in time using the automated Google Ads -> BigQuery export. Ideally values for Display, Search, etc.
I've gone through the documentation about the exports and found two tables that might be suitable - AdGroupAudienceBasicStats and CampaignAudienceBasicStats. However in neither of these two tables (or any other tables with data about audiences) I can see any data about the audience size.
Thus, I would like to know which table to use to find data about audience sizes. Or is it that audience sizes aren't exported, and we are out of luck?
